# Chrome - Offline Pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webbrowser-control

I'm taking a course online that has a terrible gui setup. Sifting through the material, which is online, is incredibly slow and annoying.

What I want to do is create a directory with everything saved and pre-loaded. I remember you used to be able to do this in older browsers, with an option called 'save for offline viewing' but I can't find such an option in chrome.

How can I get pre-loaded access to all of the course content, with my own organization structure, using chrome (or any other method).

Each 'page' contains images, video as well as text.

The player seems to be coming from chrome, and there is a 'save video as option'; the extension is mp4.

I'm not fantastic with html or javascript, but the way it is set up is unbearable so I'm open to more complex solution if need be.

Comment for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> "More Tools" -> Save Page As

Comment: I take it that this requires no internet connection, and the content won't be effected if they changed the stuff on the website?

Comment: Yes, it allows you to access the page offline, and the content will not be affected if they change it.